# Логотипы для меток на rustackoverflow

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки

На stackoverflow есть метки с логотипами для [pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pycharm/info) например. А почему такого нет у нас ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это спонсорские теги. Компания платит денюжку, SO добавляет иконку к тегу с кастомными ссылками в описание.

Такое вроде как работает только на Stack Overflow.

Comment: Вот это да! Только вот точно бы узнать работает ли у нас такое?)

Comment: @stackflow если и работает, то инициатива должна исходить от тех компаний, которые представляют бренд соответствующей метки.

Comment: Если такое будет, то скорей всего 1С за такое возмётся. Йоптаскрипт и прочее))

Comment: @stackflow не думаю, что 1С'ники в курсе таких вещей. Им это вряд ли будет интересно. А вот Яндекс могли бы.

Comment: JetBrains представлен в метках на SO (Kotlin, все IDEшки, YouTrack, TeamCity). Может их и RU.SO заинтересовал бы.